# GPU and CPU bound tasks in a signle machine

Tags: architecture, gpu, cpu

I have an API for vector calculation for single specified document in order to find later similar documents using vector comparison. It is a CPU bound task as we should do it achieving low latency (it is done at online, user is waiting for a response).

Now I want to implement a new API where list of documents accepted (batch) (it is done at offline). In this case I care more about throughput rather than latency, that's why calculations will be done on GPU. I am wandering what is the best architecture for this.
I have two options in my head.

1. We have one service which do both CPU and GPU calculations.
2. We separate them in different services. First service is in charge of online (single API), second in charge of offline (batch API).

Are there any pitfalls in using [1] approach, maybe some performance degradation? I wasn't able to find specific literature on this topic, if there are some articles please share links.

Answer (score 1):

The first choice is definitely more logical.

First, the observation that CPU's are lower latency might be true today, but this will depend quite a bit on hardware details. Don't hardcode this assumption into an API.

Secondly (and related), when running on a system without GPU, you will need to run on the CPU (with lower throughput). Again, the same principle applies. Don't encode hardware assumptions into an API.

The overhead is very low compared to the actual work. Your API takes the incoming request, and based on the type and hardware dispatches to the correct implementation. That's a handful of if-statements at most.